# How do I send a JSON object to a URL as a parameter?

Tags: json, ajax, url

There's the URL `http://na.op.gg/summoner/ajax/lpHistory/` that returns data if the variable `summonerName` (a string value) is passed to it.  How do I send it a string so it gives me useful JSON data instead of an error message `There is no target.`?

I've tried going to the URL `http://na.op.gg/summoner/ajax/lpHistory/faker` but I get the same error message.  I've also tried `http://na.op.gg/summoner/ajax/lpHistory/?faker` and `http://na.op.gg/summoner/ajax/lpHistory?faker`.

Comment: Show your code so we can help

Comment: Try JSON.stringify - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: I worked it out with Postman  thanks